# How to import QML file to another QML file in Cascades, Blackberry 10

Tags: qml, blackberry-cascades

This question maybe doesn't have anything common with Cascades, but I'm a newbe in QML so let it be. I have tabbed pane and I want to keep the contents of each page in separate files. Example:

```
TabbedPane {
    Tab {
        Page {
            //import from file page1.qml
        }
    }
    Tab {
        Page {
            //import from file page2.qml            
        }
    }
}
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Tabbed Pane {
    Tab {
        Page1 {
        }
    }
    Tab {
        Page2 {
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming Page1.qml and Page2.qml exist

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't assume that it's so simple.